# Behaviour of delete key on end-of-line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a question about the way the delete key works in Visual Studio 2008 (w/ Resharper).

If I put the cursor on the end of a line and press delete, the line is concatenated with the next line. However, the cursor has now moved to the end of the new concatenated line (as if End was pressed also), instead of remaining at the same column as before the press.

This is not all the time: some days it works as usual. ??

I have search through the settings but not found anything that would control this behaviour. Does anyone know what's going on? I realise there are some uses for this behaviour but I would like to feel I am in control of my IDE... ;-)

Thanks

Comment: This is happening to me too.  Did you ever discover how to make it stop doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this for about 2 minutes, and [it works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000818.html) without moving to EOL. Maybe it's an Editor option in Resharper that I have turned off.